# RuntimeError: Argument passed to at() was not in the map

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, onnx

I am trying to generate an ONNX file from a neural network model called [GANet](https://github.com/feihuzhang/GANet) which is made in PyTorch. However, I am facing the `RuntimeError: Argument passed to at() was not in the map` error.

System settings: Python 3.9.13 and PyTorch 1.13.0.

The model code is located [here](https://github.com/feihuzhang/GANet/blob/master/models/GANet_deep.py#L365-L410).

The code which I run to generate the onnx file:

```python
# Training settings
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch GANet Example')
parser.add_argument('--crop_height', type=int, required=True, help="crop height")
parser.add_argument('--crop_width', type=int, required=True, help="crop width")
parser.add_argument('--max_disp', type=int, default=192, help="max disp")
parser.add_argument('--resume', type=str, default='', help="resume from saved model")
parser.add_argument('--cuda', type=bool, default=True, help='use cuda?')
parser.add_argument('--kitti', type=int, default=0, help='kitti dataset? Default=False')
parser.add_argument('--kitti2015', type=int, default=0, help='kitti 2015? Default=False')
parser.add_argument('--data_path', type=str, required=True, help="data root")
parser.add_argument('--test_list', type=str, required=True, help="training list")
parser.add_argument('--save_path', type=str, default='./result/', help="location to save result")
parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, default='GANet_deep', help="model to train")

opt = parser.parse_args()



model = GANet(opt.max_disp)

print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(opt.resume))
checkpoint = torch.load(opt.resume)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'], strict=False)


model.eval()

# Input to the model
x = torch.randn(1, 3, 48, 48, requires_grad=True)
torch_out = model(x,x)
batch_size = 1


# Export the model
torch.onnx.export(model,               # model being run
                  (x,x),                         # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                  "onnxGanet.onnx",   # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                  export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                  opset_version=11,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                  do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                  input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                  output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                  dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})
                                
import onnx

onnx_model = onnx.load("onnxGanet.onnx")

# Save the ONNX model
onnx.save(onnx_model, "/home/jokar/GANet-master/onnxGanet.onnx")
```

The error I get:

```
/home/jokar/GANet-master/onnxGANet.py:95: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  assert(x.size() == rem.size())
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/modules/GANet.py:123: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  cost = x.new().resize_(num, channels * 2, self.maxdisp, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/functions/GANet.py:14: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  output = input.new().resize_(num, channels, depth, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/functions/GANet.py:15: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  temp_out = input.new().resize_(num, channels, depth, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/functions/GANet.py:16: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  mask = input.new().resize_(num, channels, depth, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/onnxGANet.py:305: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  assert(x.size() == rem.size())
/home/jokar/GANet-master/onnxGANet.py:272: TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python boolean might cause the trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values, so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
  assert(lg1.size() == lg2.size())
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/functions/GANet.py:181: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  temp_out = input.new().resize_(num, channels, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/functions/GANet.py:182: TracerWarning: resize_ can't be represented in the JIT at the moment, so we won't connect any uses of this value with its current trace. If you happen to use it again, it will show up as a constant in the graph. Consider using `view` or `reshape` to make it traceable.
  output = input.new().resize_(num, channels, height, width).zero_()
/home/jokar/GANet-master/libs/GANet/modules/GANet.py:145: TracerWarning: torch.Tensor results are registered as constants in the trace. You can safely ignore this warning if you use this function to create tensors out of constant variables that would be the same every time you call this function. In any other case, this might cause the trace to be incorrect.
  disp = Variable(torch.Tensor(np.reshape(np.array(range(self.maxdisp)),[1, self.maxdisp, 1, 1])), requires_grad=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jokar/GANet-master/onnxGANet.py", line 481, in <module>
    torch.onnx.export(model,               # model being run
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 504, in export
    _export(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 1529, in _export
    graph, params_dict, torch_out = _model_to_graph(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 1115, in _model_to_graph
    graph = _optimize_graph(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 617, in _optimize_graph
    _C._jit_pass_onnx_remove_inplace_ops_for_onnx(graph, module)
RuntimeError: Argument passed to at() was not in the map.
```